# Bokeh: How to make a multi-line plot when categories do not share the same index or x-axis reference (UPDATED)

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, line-plot

I'm trying to create a multi-line plot in Bokeh using the code below.

The plot is generated but no the data is not displayed.

What I'd like to obtain is a line plot for each item. I can do this manually in the case of a few samples, making separate line plots. But I'd like to automate this in the case a relatively large amount of categories ('items', in the data table shown below).

thanks for any feedback

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

bokeh_test=pd.read_excel(data, 'bokeh')
display(bokeh_test)

item    x   y
A   4   0.00
A   5   0.00
A   36  39.88
A   66  46.20
A   97  32.93
A   127 25.78
A   158 21.92
A   189 18.64
B   6   4.47
B   7   1.17
B   8   0.00
B   38  45.70
B   68  61.68
B   98  43.11
B   129 25.05
B   160 33.97
B   190 32.06
B   221 29.22
B   251 24.94

output_notebook()
source=ColumnDataSource(data=bokeh_test)

p = figure(plot_height=400, 
            plot_width=400,
            x_axis_label='x', 
            y_axis_label='y'
           )

p.multi_line(xs='x', 
        ys='y',
        source=source
       )

show(p)
```

UPDATE:

I found a way to to plot the data. this is the updated code and the image of the Plot. I was using Bokeh version 1.3.4. When swtiching to the last version (2.2.3) I get an error regarding CDSView not beign compatible with line plots (apparently because data is not continuous or points are not joined).

```
output_notebook()

source=ColumnDataSource(data=bokeh_test)

list1=np.unique(source.data['item']).tolist() # Getting a list for using with CDSView filters
# result = ['A', 'B']

tools = 'save, pan, box_zoom, reset, wheel_zoom,tap'
    
           
p = figure(plot_height=400, 
           plot_width=400,
           x_axis_label='x', 
           y_axis_label='y',
           toolbar_location='above',
           tools=tools
           )

color=['red', 'blue', 'green']

for i in range(len(list1)):
    view=CDSView(source=source, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='item', group=list1[i])])
    p.line(x='x', 
           y='y',
           source=source,
           line_color=color[i],
           view=view,
           legend=list1[i],
           line_width=2
          )
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding `x_range=['A', 'B']` to the call to `figure(...)`. Later, you will be able to update it by assigning to `p.x_range.factors`.

Comment: Hi @EugenePakhomov, I updated the original post. I found an answer to what I wanted to do, but now I get an error when switching to a newer version of Bokeh

Comment: Your update has absolutely nothing to do with the original question, so you should've just asked a new one. Either way, what you get is not an error but a warning, and a rather self-descriptive one.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Added the labels object and placing it in the x_range option of the figure.

```python
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
    
labels = ['nd1', 's02', 'dr2', 'dr1', 'df2', 'df3']
p = figure(width=300, height=300, x_range=labels)
p.multi_line(
    xs=[labels]*2,
    ys=[[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 8, 7, 2], [4, 0, 7, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]],
    color=['red','green']
)
show(p)
```